# MariaDB - Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/DietPi.lower-test - but every permission OK

Tags: installation, mariadb, debian-based

I write here my issue, because other forum don't know how to fix it.
Link to original topic: https://dietpi.com/forum/t/mariadb-instal-failed/16524/3

I would like to:
Fix the program without reinstallation of the PC.

Full status:

```
root@DietPi:~# systemctl status mariadb
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5.18 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
             └─dietpi.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-04-27 12:13:06 BST; 23min ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 772 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 776 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 778 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 829 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mariadbd $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)                                                        
   Main PID: 829 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"
        CPU: 114ms

ápr 27 12:13:05 DietPi systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.5.18 database server...
ápr 27 12:13:06 DietPi mariadbd[829]: 2023-04-27 12:13:06 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (mysqld 10.5.18-MariaDB-0+deb11u1) starting as process 829 ...
ápr 27 12:13:06 DietPi mariadbd[829]: 2023-04-27 12:13:06 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/DietPi.lower-test
ápr 27 12:13:06 DietPi mariadbd[829]: [92B blob data]
ápr 27 12:13:06 DietPi mariadbd[829]: 2023-04-27 12:13:06 0 [ERROR] Aborting
ápr 27 12:13:06 DietPi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
ápr 27 12:13:06 DietPi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.                                           
ápr 27 12:13:06 DietPi systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.5.18 database server.
```

Comment: There's significant information in your original link that isn't here. What is the filesystem an mount options of `/mnt/dietpi_userdata` from which `/var/lib/mysql` symlinks?

Comment: I reinstalled couple of times and tried to solve the issue (link data maybe outdated). Yes, the system has mount point. Now the link for the `/var/lib/mysql`

`root@DietPi:~# ls -l /var/lib/
összesen 76
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root     root   26 ápr   27 13.54 mysql -> /mnt/dietpi_userdata/mysql`

Comment: `root@DietPi:~# ls -l /mnt/dietpi_userdata/
összesen 68
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql          mysql     4096 ápr   28 07.19 mysql`

Comment: Now touch is working, but the error is the same
`sudo -u mysql -g mysql touch ./mysql/demo.file`

`ápr 28 07:26:28 DietPi mariadbd[794]: 2023-04-28 7:26:28 0 [Warning] Can’t create test file /var/lib/mysql/DietPi.lower-test`

Comment: *filesystem* of `/mnt/dietpi_userdata` and *mount options*? Add by editing the question. There's not enough space in comments to develop a follow forum like format.